# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions set client ID programmatically based on the users E-Mail/Domain

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, oauth, saml, claims-based-identity

I have an existing public website written in MVC 4 which uses forms authentication and has user accounts configured in a SQL DB.  I have a brief to add a single sign-on functionality which I have got working in this way.  A user account will be created in our SQL where the E-Mail will match that of the active directory sign-in.  This currently works, I can visit my app and it will auto-log me in.

I have configured an app registration in azure active directory which has given me the client ID and App Key to use.  This is all well and good but as currently configured this limits me to only allowing one client to sign up for our service using single-sign on.  What I would like to do is to configure a table which will store the domain, client ID and app key together so that when a visitor accesses the site we are able to "detect" their domain or email and thus find the client id and app key to use for THEIR active directory.  This is a public facing website and it MUST continue to support the standard forms authentication login AND allow organisations to access it using their existing login credentials for their AD.

I also will need to look at how to default to the standard web form login page if no valid domain/client ID is found to allow users to log in as normal.

I would LOVE some help right now.  For reference I am using the Startup.Auth.cs which visual studio kindly generated for me to handle the handshake.  I have included the pertinent code below with notes and changes.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId, <--------- HERE THE CLIENT ID IS SET FROM A VARIABLE HARD CODED ABOVE
                    Authority = authority,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            var email = context.JwtSecurityToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "unique_name").Value;                            

                            ###################################################################
                            HERE I HAVE GOT THE E-MAIL SO I AM ABLE TO FIND THE DOMAIN AND FIND THE 
                            CLIENT ID I NEED, BUT I NEED TO FIND THIS BEFORE THE LINE
                            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication WHERE WE USE THE CLIENT ID
                            ###################################################################
                            string[] EMailAddress = email.Split('@');
                            CallResponse callResponse = BusinessObjectSSO.SSO_GetApplicationDetailsByDomain(EMailAddress[1]);
                            if (callResponse.ResponseCode == 0)
                            {
                                DomainApplication domainApplication = (DomainApplication)callResponse.ReturnData;
                                clientId = domainApplication.ClientID;
                                appKey = domainApplication.Secret;
                            }

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri("http://localhost:51437/"), credential, graphResourceID).Result;
                            SessionClass.SSOEMail = result.UserInfo.DisplayableId;

                            CallResponse callResponseUser = BusinessObjectSSO.SSO_AssignUserIDFromEMailAddress(signedInUserID, result.UserInfo.DisplayableId);
                            SessionClass.SSOUserID = Convert.ToInt32(callResponseUser.ReturnData);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("Account/Error");
                            context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please note that the ClientId has nothing to do with the user. The clientId identifies the client (e.g. website). So this will never change for the website.

Comment: The client ID came from creating an app registration in my active directory.  When this is available for multiple clients, will they not need to enter an app registration in their own AD which will give them a new client id?

Comment: Do you mean [client or user](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html#user)? The clientId should be unique per instance. Instead of using the hard-coded value you can read it from a configuration file. After installation of the app, there is no need to change the value anymore. Because the (instance of this) client doesn't change anymore. If you want to set values dynamically, e.g. acr_values then you can do that in Notifications.RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification -> context.ProtocolMessage. I'm sure ClientId can also be set there, but I don't think you should.

Comment: Say I have 2 organisations who want to be able to access my application; each organisation will have to register the app in their active directory yes?

Will each organisation get a unique application (client) id or will microsoft give them the same ID because of the application endpoints or will each organisation get a unique application (client) id?